# Cast loseless long to float

Tags: java

Long have 8 bytes in Java. Float have 4 bytes

Why I can do:

```
    long a = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    float b = a;
```

Instead of:

```
long a = Long.MAX_VALUE;
float b = (float) a;
```

The result is:

`9223372036854775807 <-- LONG
9223372036854776000,000000 <-- float`

So why If I lost precision I dont have to say explicite cast '(float)' ?

Comment: [JLS-5.1.2. Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) - *19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening primitive conversions:* among them *`long` to `float` or `double`*

Comment: Note that even for long to double, you still lose precision, even though both are 64 bit (if the long exceeds 2^53)

Comment: That JLS section even makes a point of saying: “A widening conversion of an `int` or a `long` value to `float`, or of a `long` value to `double`, may result in *loss of precision* - that is, the result may lose some of the least significant bits of the value. In this case, the resulting floating-point value will be a correctly rounded version of the integer value, using IEEE 754 round-to-nearest mode…”